# DrawDebugSphere obscured by invisible object

Tags: lumen, unreal-engine5

I'm following a course, and noticed my debug sphere doesn't render at certain areas of my screen. [Here's a quick image to show that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZn7D.png)

What's interesting is if I switch the view modes from lit to unlit, it fixes the render issue. Same goes for Nanite view. If I switch to Lumen however, it is broken again.

Also note the sphere should be rendering from the middle, thus half should be on the floor and half below it, but in my case the whole sphere is rendered in lit mode, as it was sitting on top of the floor. [Here's a short video about this.](https://streamable.com/axrili)

I tried messing with GI, camera position but couldn't find a way to fix this. The only useful thing I found was the view modes. Also this happens in all of my projects, so it's not project specific, probably engine or version specific. Using UE5.3. Was happening in UE5.2 as well.